# Replace {myParameter} by its value in a string

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, substitution

I am wondering an easy way to resolve the `{myParameterX}` by its value in a string.

I have a section in my xml (obviously simplified for the post) that holds the parameters definitions and a set of string to "translate":

```
<section>
    <parameters>
        <myParameter1>One</myParameter1>
        <myParameter2>Two</myParameter2>
    </parameters>
    <field toTranslate="{myParameter1} + {myParameter1} = {myParameter2}"/>
    <field toTranslate="{myParameter2} - {myParameter1} = {myParameter1}"/>
</section>
```

In the end I expect something like:

```
<field translated="One + One = Two"/>
<field translated="Two - One = One"/>
```

I think the solution is near but I keep getting nasty error about invalid charachters in my regex (`Unexpected token ")" in path expression`). I have tried to escape and escape the escape characters but I can't get it :(

```
<xsl:template name="resolve">
    <xsl:param name="toResolve" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="parameters" as="element()"/>

    <xsl:analyze-string regex="{(.+)}" select="$toResolve">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="pName" select="regex-group(1)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$parameters/$pName"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:call-template name="resolve">
    <xsl:with-param name="toResolve" select="field/@toTranslate"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="parameters" select="parameters"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Note, I am using xslt 2.0
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<xsl:analyze-string regex="\{{(.+?)\}}" select="$toResolve">`.

Here is a complete sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field/@toTranslate">
  <xsl:variable name="field" select=".."/>
  <xsl:attribute name="translated">
    <xsl:analyze-string regex="\{{(.+?)\}}" select=".">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="pName" select="regex-group(1)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$field/../parameters/*[local-name() eq $pName]"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforms

```
<section>
    <parameters>
        <myParameter1>One</myParameter1>
        <myParameter2>Two</myParameter2>
    </parameters>
    <field toTranslate="{myParameter1} + {myParameter1} = {myParameter2}"/>
    <field toTranslate="{myParameter2} - {myParameter1} = {myParameter1}"/>
</section>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><section>
    <parameters>
        <myParameter1>One</myParameter1>
        <myParameter2>Two</myParameter2>
    </parameters>
    <field translated="One + One = Two"/>
    <field translated="Two - One = One"/>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find the way to escape properly the regex in xsl?

Comment: Are you asking for a documentation? Or a function to escape? There are two problems, the `regex` attribute allows attribute value templates (XSLT syntax) so curly braces `{` and `}` need to be duplicated to be interpreted literally, and inside a regular expression pattern the curly braces are used to delimit a quantifier (e.g. `a{5,10}` matches 5 to 10 `a` characters) so for the regular expression to treat the braces literally we need `\{` respectively ``}`. Together that results in `regex="\{{(.+?)\}}"`.

Comment: As for a function that would escape the `{` as `\{`, see http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html.

Comment: ok, thanks, I was missing the first bit of your explanation (duplicate the curly braces). thx